# vscode code navigation "Failed to get sources."

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCODE to develop codes in Java with "Java Extension Pack". I encountered the issue that the code navigation of vscode doesn't work as expected.

Previously, I can use "Ctrl+Click"(please see the description: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved) to check the definitions from Java packages, such as java.util.HashMap etc.

However, after re-install my OS, the code navigation didn't work as expected. Unlike some posts online(please see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/966 or https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/756), in my case, it works but it shows .class file with such comments on the top of the file. Let me use the Hashmap as the example.

/* HashMap.class */

```
// Failed to get sources. Instead, stub sources have been generated by the disassembler.
// Implementation of methods is unavailable.
package java.util;
public class HashMap<K,V> extends java.util.AbstractMap implements java.util.Map, java.lang.Cloneable, java.io.Serializable { 
 // many declartions for methods below
 ...
 }
```

What I need is navigating to the HashMap.java rather than HashMap.class.
I use "Setting Sync" extension which restores all my previous settings, so I don't think there are any issues about my setting. I still will provide some related User settings below

```
  "java.classPath": [],

  // Specifies the folder path to the JDK (8 or more recent) used to launch the Java Language Server.
  "java.home": null,

  // Installation directory of Java 8
  "java.home": "",

  // Traces the communication between VS Code and the Java language server.
  "java.trace.server": "off",
```

More info:

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

VSCODE version: 1.22.2

openjdk version "1.8.0_162"

Any help will be appreciated! Thank yoU!

Answer (score 7):

For ubuntu users, you could try the command line below

```
sudo apt install openjdk-{jdk version}-source
```

Comment: In addition, you can search which sources are available: ```sudo apt-cache search openjdk | grep source```

Comment: @cxsy Thanks a lot. I wanted to see my java doc in VScode like in IntelliJ and this solved the problem. Now I can see what method/class by pressing Ctrl+Click.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, except with a source jar in my local repository rather than HashMap.

I fixed it by quitting Visual Studio Code, removing all the `.classpath`, `.factorypath`, and `.project` files (my project has submodules so there are multiple of these), then reopening VS Code and letting it find everything again.

There's likely a more elegant way to do this but brute force worked.

Comment: Awesome - this worked for me!